# how can i work out the percentage of rows with matching values in 2 different columns?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I'm trying to find out the percentage of my users which return to my site by comparing their 'Joined' date and their 'Last Seen' date.

In more literal terms, I have a table which looks a bit like this:

| username |    Joined     |Last Seen | 
|----------|:-------------:|---------:| 
|   user1  |   3434626     | 4134526  | 
|   user2  |   3434668     | 3434668  | 
|   user3  |   3434646     | 4134579  |

And I want to find the percentage of users who have a different Join date to Last seen date.

Comment: In `R`: find out all matching pairs using `which`, calculate how many there are using `length`, and divide by the total number obtained using `length`: `length(which(data[,"Joined"]==data[,"Last Seen"]))/length(data[,"Joined"])`. Your matrix has to be named "data".

Comment: From the comments there seems be an assumption of using [tag:r], is that accurate? If so, could you tag the question with that language (or, if not [tag:r], with the appropriate language that you *are* using)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are using a spreadsheet, it's quite simple. I know this is primitive, but it may be a simple way to achieve your desired result.

1. Subtract Joined from Last Seen [=C2-B2] to receive either 0 where
   they are the same, or a positive value if not.
2. Count the amount of cells with a value greater than 0
   [=COUNTIF(D2:D4,">0")]
3. Divide by a count of all the
   cells in the row [=COUNT(D2:D4)]

Final cell formula: [=COUNTIF(D2:D4,">0")/COUNT(D2:D4)]

4. Format this cell as a percentage.

google doc of this method here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eYG0GGGDkAe-Dzzmpp4sBIPmlqf5VkYdhwVh54myY38/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in R with following code:

```
> ddf
  username  Joined LastSeen
1    user1 3434626  4134526
2    user2 3434668  3434668
3    user3 3434646  4134579

> ddf$returned = with(ddf, ifelse(LastSeen != Joined, 1, 0))
> ddf
  username  Joined LastSeen returned
1    user1 3434626  4134526        1
2    user2 3434668  3434668        0
3    user3 3434646  4134579        1

> 100* nrow(ddf[ddf$returned>0,])/nrow(ddf)
[1] 66.66667
```